# Play Framework: Don't change URL after form validation failed

Tags: rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

In a plain Play application I have the following scenario.

A route file which looks like this:

```
GET        /accounts/add        controllers.Accounts.add()
POST       /accounts            controllers.Accounts.create()
```

The first route results in a view where I can add a new account. The form to submit the new account looks something like this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Accounts.create()) {...}
```

Now the controller binds the input to the form and checks for any validation errors:

```
public static Result create() {
    Form<Account> form = Form.form(Account.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.account.add.render(form));
    }
    ...
}
```

Now the thing is, the client will see the same view with some additional error messages. However, meanwhile the URL has changed from http://example.com/accounts/add to http://example.com/accounts.

If the client now reloads the browser this calls GET http://example.com/accounts (which isn't even mapped in this scenario - thus getting a 404 - Not Found).

Maybe it's just me but I find this kind of annoying and browsing some GitHub projects I couldn't find a good solution for this case.

Of cause things would be much simpler if the second route is rewritten to:

```
POST        /accounts/add        controllers.Accounts.create()
```

... in which case everything works fine. But from a REST point of view this doesn't feel good either. The same applies to update scenarios (having GET /accounts/:id/update vs. PUT /accounts/:id).

Is there a guide on how to handle this? Am I getting something wrong or is this no problem at all (from a pragmatic point of view)?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by saying "But from a REST point of view this doesn't feel good either"?

Comment: Sure. I want new account resources to be created by performing a POST to /accounts (not to /accounts/new) because this 'feels right', i.e. the semantics are clear by looking at the route definition.

Having to perform a POST to /accounts/new might confuse other clients if they are using the same API.

As I said, maybe this is not as much of a problem as I think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to leave the previous URL because a request for a new address has already been made. A controller only provides response for a requested resource. To go to the previous URL you could only make a redirect in case of validation failure but you would lost errors that way so this is not a solution.

I suggest mapping both actions with the same URL. This way you would solve problem with the browser reload.

If you create a REST service for http clients that aren't browsers you will probably want to serve different response than a simple http page. The separation of actions for particular clients could be a good solution for keeping REST API clean and a browser user happy.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I also thought about the redirect and you are right, this is not really a solutions since I'd have to keep track of the context (maybe using the flash scope or something).

So eventually I might use the same URL but I'd like to hear some more thoughts on it.